# Change color/ background of current active page in navigation bar

Tags: php, jquery, css, ssi, server-side-includes

I'm designing my mobile website and using big tabs for navigation links, how can I show which page the user is currently on e.g the link background is red for example, without manually changing the css on each link per separate page.

My page uses a server side include using PHP for my header which includes my navigation. How can I add a class to separate pages this way?

Comment: I suggest you to use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for responsive layouts

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using pure CSS.

Watch these reference videos.

[Part - 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tS_ns96LrAU)
[Part - 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-FV2dzYgE8)

Hope it helps.

Comment: For small statics sites, this can be applied. Else becomes tedious for Dynamic Sites, you need to opt for jQuery then.

Comment: The above concept is for Nav Bar, but you can get the concept from here, pretty much the same.

Comment: The website will only have about 5/6 pages max, so maybe I should apply a class if it is the easiest way

Comment: If it's only 6-7 pages, then you can go ahead with the above video concepts.